# How do I print the index from two different lists? i.e., [1, 2, 3] and [a, b, c] becomes [(1, a), (2, b), (3, c)]

Tags: python, python-3.x

> You are given two lists of the same length. Using list comprehension, write
>   a Python function to return a merged or combined list of the two lists
>   in the form of a list of tuples. For example, if your two lists are `[1, 2, 3]` and `["a", "b", "c"]`, then you should return `[(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")]`.

I can't figure out how to index the two lists to put them together

I got multiple errors because I couldn't concatenate two lists together.

Comment: show us the code of your attempt

Comment: Look up `zip()`.

Comment: You should avoid posting questions like these, which seem like an exercise you've been given and you have not put any effort in resolving

Answer (score 4):

The `zip()` function take iterables (can be zero or more), makes iterator that aggregates elements based on the iterables passed, and returns an iterator of tuples.

```
 [ (a,b) for (a,b) in zip([1,2,3],['a','b','c']) ]
```

Comment: `[x for x in something]` -> `list(something)`

Comment: Also if the first sequence is a count (1,2,3, ...) you can do ```enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c'], 1)``` or ```zip(itertools.count(1), ['a', 'b', 'c'])```

Comment: Or, even easier, `list(zip([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']))`.

Comment: Or even better: ```list(zip([1,2,3], 'abc'))```

Comment: All of these answers make sense, but it is mentioned that he needs list comprehension.